# Making white pixels in canvas transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

im trying to create a script that changes the color of images, i found a way to change the color, but since the images have a white background it changes ALL of the image, is it possible to ignore the white pixels somehow?

This is the code so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<h4>Original Image</h4>
<img id="testImage" src='../src/test.png'/>

<h4>Image copied to canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<h4>Modified Image copied to an image tag</h4>
<img id="imageData"/>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
image = document.getElementById("testImage");

ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 128, 128),
    pix = imgd.data,
    uniqueColor = [0,0,150]; // Blue for an example, can change this value to be anything.

// Loops through all of the pixels and modifies the components.
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
      pix[i] = uniqueColor[0];   // Red component
      pix[i+1] = uniqueColor[1]; // Blue component
      pix[i+2] = uniqueColor[2]; // Green component
      //pix[i+3] is the transparency.
}

ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);


var savedImageData = document.getElementById("imageData");
savedImageData.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are going to want to use @aglassman 's answers. But make a canvas element for your image and processes it at startup. Then draw the canvas element to the canvas. This will dramatically increase performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
    if (pix[i] == 255 &&  
        pix[i+1] == 255 &&
        pix[i+2] == 255)
    {
    //pixel is white
    }
    else
    {
    //pixel is not white, modify it.
    }
```

Comment: i've tried to get that to work, doesnt seem to do the trick tho (i might be placing it wrong im no expert)
How would i place that piece of code?

Comment: Sorry did it with your code now, and it works. You're awesome thank you.

Comment: It works for some images, others don't, very strange. Seems to not work when i get the image from the web.

Comment: That is odd.  I would try firbug for firefox, and debug your JavaScript on an image that fails.  That should pinpoint the fail point.  Good Luck!

Comment: I dont really know how to use firebugs debugger, with google chrome i get SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 between:
 
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 250, 250),
(error here)
pix = imgd.data,
Searched some and they said it might be coz i go to the site by c:// and not localhost, but i dont. Trying to solve it but cant find the issue.

Comment: That seems like a new issue, try posing that as a new question.  Someone else may have more experience with that error.